# Is the output of filter() on a Java parallel stream also parallel? (chaining filters, executed in parallel)

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, chain

The following code applies a chain of filters to a `Stream` and then counts the number of resulting items:

```java
public int countNumberOfFailedStudentsUnder20(
            final Student[] studentArray) {
        return (int) Stream.of(studentArray)
              .parallel()
              .filter(s -> !s.checkIsCurrent())
              .parallel()
              .filter(s -> s.getAge() > 20)
              .parallel()
              .filter(s -> s.getGrade() < 65)
              .count();
    }
```

Is the output of each subsequent filter a parallel stream (while the initial stream was made parallel by calling `parallel()`) or it must be converted to a parallel stream explicitly, like it presently is.

Comment: It's parallel already. Those extra calls are useless.

Comment: Related: [Java Stream API - Parallel and Sequential Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63112716/6395627)

Comment: So, the ```filter()``` effectively returns the same stream, but filtered, right?

Comment: No, that's imprecise. Filter returns a stream containing the instruction that filtering should happen when a terminal operation, like `count`, runs. The actual stream is not filtered until the end. Likewise, `parallel` does nothing but set a flag saying "this should be run in parallel", which is not checked again until the terminal operation. That's why multiple calls to `parallel` just equates to setting a flag that's already set.

Comment: Now I get it. It resembles an SQL query. Thank you, Michael, for the explanation, and Slaw, for the link.